# Azure Graph API - Device Mgmt. does not return all systems

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, endpoint, azure-ad-graph-api, device-management

I have sent the following call to the Microsoft Graph API: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices here I get a list of devices, but it is incomplete. Client and server systems are missing, which our customer can see via the web interface (endpoint.microsoft.com). The first thought was that the client systems are not in Intune, but this isn't true. If I now make my subsequent query for the individual devices and take an ID that does not come from the response but from the interface of the customer, I get an "internal server error". I have made the following queries: [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/{DeviceId}/windowsProtectionState](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/%7BDeviceId%7D/windowsProtectionState) [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/{DeviceId}/windowsProtectionState/detectedMalwareState](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/%7BDeviceId%7D/windowsProtectionState/detectedMalwareState)

Is it possible to get a logical error message there?

How to retrieve the information for server systems and what can be the reason that we do not get all client system?

Answer (score 0):

The complete data (Device) might be not coming in a single page there will a next page link for see the rest of devices (Missing Server and Client System)

[image]

Use the @odata. next link API to get the Rest of missing System

[image]

---

Here is one more alternative way you can get the List of Client and Server System(Including Manage and Unmanaged).

API for Server System Details:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices?$count=true&$filter=startswith(operatingSystem, 'Windows Server')

[image]

API for Client System Details

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices?$count=true&$filter=startswith(operatingSystem, 'Windows')

[image]

**Note**: Based on version you can also filter like Windows 10 or Window Sever 2012 Datacentre

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/device-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply and sorry for my late reply.
I had already implemented the next page link in the code.
Using the resource https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/devices?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName, '<DeviceName>') I get the system displayed but in the end I don't get the data I need.

Comment: The goal is to get the pattern information from all client and server systems.

Currently I use the resource https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/<DeviceID>/windowsProtectionState and https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/<DeviceID>/windowsProtectionState/detectedMalwareState

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices?$count=true&$filter=startswith(operatingSystem,'Windows Server')
I do not get any systems back

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices?$count=true&$filter=startswith(operatingSystem,'Windows')
Gives me a big list including the servers which have only 'Windows' in the operatingSystem.

But here I don't get the pattern information I would like to have

Comment: Please refer this doc(https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/api-reference/beta/api/intune-devices-windowsmanageddevice-get.md) and check if it helps.